# \triangleleftneq and \trianglerightneq commands?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amssymb

There are certain 6-tuples of commands, such as:

- `\subset`, `\subseteq`, `\subsetneq`, `\supset`, `\supseteq`, `\supsetneq`
- `<`, `\leq`, `\lneq`, `>`, `\geq`, `\gneq`

There are also commands `\triangleleft`, `\trianglelefteq`, `\triangleright`, and `\trianglerighteq`. However, when I tried to use the commands `\triangleleftneq` and `\trianglerightneq`, which I presumed would have been defined in `amssymb`, I received the error, `Undefined control sequence.`

Are there any packages that define these commands? I tried to find them in Detexify, but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Try `\ntrianglelefteq`

Comment: i don't know of any font that contains these symbols.  they weren't in the collection compiled for stix, and thus didn't get into unicode.  if you have evidence of their appearance in a published source. let me know, and i will submit them to unicode, with good likelihood of their acceptance.  until then, your best bet is to add a vertical closure to the open end of the greater or less of `\gneq` and `\lneq`, but this will work well in only the main size; if you need smaller versions (for sub/superscripts), it can be done, but is more complicated.  (i will try tomorrow.)

Comment: The symbol you are looking for does not exist (at least not in Unicode).  It seems as you have to draw it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments say this doesn't exist as standard.  Here is one way to construct the symbols for use in usual display size:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx,amsmath}

\newcommand{\trianglerightneq}{\mathrel{\ooalign{\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\reflectbox{\rotatebox{90}{$\nshortmid$}}}\cr$\triangleright$\cr}\mkern-3mu}}
\newcommand{\triangleleftneq}{\mathrel{\reflectbox{$\trianglerightneq$}}}

\begin{document}

\( a \trianglerightneq b \triangleleftneq c \)

\end{document}
```